# The total size of the argument list and exported variables exceeds the OS limit of 1MB

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort, macos, exec

I was doing a grid search for some scientific computing project, and got a bunch of log files with parameters embedded in the filenames.

```bash
$ ls -l | wc -l
   38210
$ ls -l | tail
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel  1070 Jul 20 15:01 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda0_kappa0.25.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel  1070 Jul 20 15:00 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda0_kappa0.5.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel  1070 Jul 20 15:01 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda0_kappa0.75.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel  1070 Jul 20 15:00 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda0_kappa0.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel  1070 Jul 20 15:01 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda0_kappa1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel   981 Jul 20 15:06 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda1_kappa0.25.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel   981 Jul 20 15:08 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda1_kappa0.5.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel   981 Jul 20 15:08 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda1_kappa0.75.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel   981 Jul 20 15:06 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda1_kappa0.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 qys  wheel   984 Jul 20 15:08 gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda1_kappa1.txt
```

Each file looks something like

```bash
$ cat gmm_dim96_aelr0.01_ufactor100_K8_R8_lr1_lambda1_kappa1.txt
GMM: epoch 0: train loss 662699.9375, valid accuracy 80.03%
GMM: epoch 1: train loss 662553.75, valid accuracy 79.92%
GMM: epoch 2: train loss 662446.1875, valid accuracy 79.77%
GMM: epoch 3: train loss 662429.5, valid accuracy 79.82%
GMM: epoch 4: train loss 662404.5625, valid accuracy 79.83%
GMM: epoch 5: train loss 662395.0625, valid accuracy 79.85%
GMM: epoch 6: train loss 662381.25, valid accuracy 79.85%
GMM: epoch 7: train loss 662370.25, valid accuracy 79.83%
GMM: epoch 8: train loss 662362.875, valid accuracy 79.86%
GMM: epoch 9: train loss 662353.6875, valid accuracy 79.84%
GMM: epoch 10: train loss 662343.4375, valid accuracy 79.83%
GMM: epoch 11: train loss 662335.0625, valid accuracy 79.83%
GMM: epoch 12: train loss 662325.5, valid accuracy 79.85%
GMM: epoch 13: train loss 662316.6875, valid accuracy 79.87%
GMM: epoch 14: train loss 662307.0625, valid accuracy 79.88%
GMM: epoch 15: train loss 662298.0625, valid accuracy 79.90%
GMM: end: test accuracy 80.38%
```

I want to sort the parameter configurations by their evaluation accuracy with `grep`, but got the following error

```bash
$ grep 'GMM: epoch 15: ' gmm_*ufactor100*.txt | sort -k 9 -n -r | head
exec: Failed to execute process '/usr/bin/grep': the total size of the argument list and exported variables (2.1MB) exceeds the OS limit of 1MB.
```

How do I allow a larger size of the argument list? I am on macOS Monterey in case it's relevant.

Comment: `man xargs`/google xargs

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Oh right! I did `find . -name 'gmm_*ufactor100*.txt' | xargs grep 'GMM: epoch 15: ' | sort -k 9 -n -r | head` and it works!

Comment: `find -print0 | xargs -0` could be safer.